# Applying for US visas without being a permanent resident of that country, is this possible?

Tags: visas, usa, applications, nigerian-citizens

I am from Nigeria, I have been able to get some travel history. So i wanted to ask something here which seems a bit confusing.

I read from here https://www.alllaw.com/articles/nolo/us-immigration/applying-for-nonimmigrant-visa-which-consulate.html That I can apply for US visas outside of my home country, since I would be visiting another country, I wanted to confirm if this is true.

I also see that in places like Dominican republic, something like this here https://do.usembassy.gov/soliciting-u-s-tourism-visa-third-country-national/ , I can apply without being a resident. I wanted to know if this applies as rule of thumb to other embassies? Not a first time traveler, but we have issue of dates here in Nigeria , hence this question. So since I would be visiting other countries I decided to first inquire here.

Comment: You can, but you should expect heightened scrutiny and less familiarity with your documents from your home country.

Comment: @xngtng so suppose i go to some place like Fiji , i can apply from there? without being a resident?

Comment: You also need to factor in the time it might take to get your passport returned, if you have to submit it with your application, and the length of time you are allowed to stay as a visitor in whatever country you wish to apply from. You could have a big problem if a decision is protracted and you are without your passport and not in your country of residence.

Comment: @Joy: you can apply also in Fiji, but it is read as a red flag (if you do not have a valid reason), and very probably both embassies (Fiji and Nigeria) will check your application. And being from Nigeria doesn't help (too much illegal immigration from that country [and being a very populous country doesn't help statistics]).

Comment: What does ‘some travel history’ mean in practice? Do you meet **all** the eligibility criteria? If your travel history doesn’t include equivalent jurisdictions eg Schengen, Canada, the answer will likely be a refusal, meaning you’ll have wasted the cost of the trip to Fiji *and* considerably worsened your travel history.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible? **Yes**

Ideally you should schedule an appointment for your visa interview at the U.S. Embassy or Consulate in the country where you live, but the U.S. does not *require* visitors to apply in their home country.

Source: https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html

Is it a good idea? **Not necessarily**

- It may be more difficult to qualify for a visa outside of the country where you live.  You should expect heightened scrutiny and less familiarity with your documents from your home country
- You need to factor in the time it might take to get your passport returned, if you have to submit it with your application, and the length of time you are allowed to stay as a visitor in whatever country you wish to apply from
- If your application is weak in any way, for example your travel history doesn’t include equivalent jurisdictions such as Schengen, Canada etc, the answer will likely be a refusal. You will have wasted the cost of the trip to another country to apply, and damaged your travel history too.